# Unable to plot without x window system, vtkInterface

Tags: python, python-3.x, vtk

I'm having problems with Python. I tried to write these simple lines of code using vtkInterface but it gives me a message of error like 'Unable to plot without x window system'. I've already installed X11 on Mac. Does somebody have an idea to fix it? Thank you

```
import vtkInterface
from vtkInterface import examples
mesh = vtkInterface.PolyData(examples.planefile)
mesh.Plot(color='orange')
```

Comment: Maintainer of vtkInterface here.  Sorry about that, looks like it's a bug on my end.  Give me bit to test it out locally on Mac OS and get a better multi-platform solution.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it’s an issue with limited Mac OS testing. I removed the xserver check for the plot command as it’s redundant and only necessary for automated testing.

I've updated vtkInterface to 0.11.3 is on pypi at [vtkInterface](https://pypi.org/project/vtkInterface/).  Please install with:

```
pip install vtkInterface --upgrade
```